# BizTalk - Flat file schema, Date with format and padding zero

Tags: biztalk, flat-file

Have a positional flat file schema with date as data type. We have format as ddMMyy. We have a requirement where 000000 needs to be allowed in date field.

When 000000 is passed in the flat file, we are getting Date is not in valid Gregorian date format.

To resolve this I have tried padding with padding character 0 and min occurs as 0. This make 000000 as valid value but it is not taking real valid date values.

Apart from regex expression, is there any way I can have this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

If the field might contain "000000" then you can't use a date/datetime type on it.

Instead, treat it as a String for the Flat File.

You should the conversion from/to the 6 char value in a Map.  The Flat File properties don't give you enough options.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the data type, you could create a new type with xsd:union that accepts any Date and String with the restriction "000000".

[xsd:union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256202(v=vs.110).aspx)